# How to iterate on the rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spotify, spotipy

I am creating a script that takes a dataframe of artists, passes them to the Spotify API and returns some extra information.  I'm struggling with how best to pass the dataframe of artists iteratively to the function which calls Spotify.

I have two functions:

```
artists = grabArtists()
```

which returns a list of artists such as:

```
0                                      Gas
1                                   System
3                       Finlay Shakespeare
4                         Boards Of Canada
6    Delia Derbyshire Appreciation Society
```

Then I have the function grab the Spotify Artist Data...

```
def grabSpotifyData(searchQ):

# ERASE CACHE AND PROMPT FOR USER PERMISSION
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials()
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

# SEARCH FOR AN ARTIST
searchQuery = searchQ
search = sp.search(searchQuery, 1, 0, "artist")

artist = search['artists']['items'][0]

genres = artist['genres']
image = artist['images'][0]['url']
pop = artist['popularity']
followers = artist['followers']['total']

return genres, image, pop, followers
```

I can grab a dataframe for a single result quite simply with the following.  How can I make this iterative so that it loops thru the artist list and appends the context about the artist?

```
artists = grabArtists()[0]
result = grabSpotifyData(artists)
df = pd.DataFrame([(artists), (result[0]), (result[1]), (result[2]), 
(result[3])])
df = df.T
```

It should return a dataframe where the columns are: Artist, Genres, Images, Popularity, Followers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass artists as a list iteratively to the api:

```
df = []
for artist in artists:
    result = grabSpotifyData(artist)
    d0 = pd.DataFrame([(artists), (result[0]), (result[1]), (result[2], (result[3])])
    df.append(d0)

df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for artist in artists:
    try:
        results = grabSpotifyData(artist)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    df = df.append(results)

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.reset_index()
```